# How to pop viewcontroller in xcode6.1 story board?

Tags: ios, storyboard

Im using story board application. I want to add a button and when click on it I need to pop to the previous `viewcontroller`.

`

```
 -(IBAction)done:(UIStoryboardSegue *)seque
 {
      [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
 }
```

`

But this is not working even though I set the action on exit on that button. But nothing happen. What should I do?

Please help me

thanks

Comment: Try this  [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

Comment: what IBAction is it? what calls it?

Comment: Its working now, I have set the action to the exit  but now I set the event to the file owner. now my above code is working

Answer (score 0):

It depends on whether your current ViewController was presented modally or via push. `popViewControllerAnimated` lets you pop the current `ViewController` which was added via push. As this takes no effect in your example, you most likely did present your ViewController modally requiring to call `[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil]` to get rid of it.